# Add An Event Handler or Listener to IWebElement's?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using a Timer to get text values from 4 values that are in a list of type ReadOnlyCollection. Is there a way to 'ADD' a listener to these 4 values to process the values when they change instead of using a Timer? Here is my current code in the Timer tick() event handler...

```
// Code in my Timer tick() method
 
               for (int i = 0; i < stockWatchListTableRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 0 && i != 1 && i != stockWatchListTableRows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        row = stockWatchListTableRows[i];

                        // tds is a ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>
                        var tds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("span"));

                        string symbol = tds[0].GetAttribute("textContent");
                        string stock = tds[1].GetAttribute("textContent");
                        string price = tds[2].GetAttribute("textContent");  // NEED text changed event handler for this one the MOST, the other ones are secondary.
                        string change = tds[3].GetAttribute("textContent");

                        // get the existing price and see if the new price is greater or less than that

                        channelingStocksData csdata;
                        csdata = stockDictionary[symbol];
                        tblist = csdata.tbl;
                        string currentPrice = String.Empty;
                        string existingPrice = String.Empty;
                        bool bPriceIncreasing = true;

                        // get the textboxes for the current and support price
                        TextBox currentPriceTB = tblist[(int)TLPColumnNames.Current_Price];

                        // get the price before it increases
                        existingPrice = currentPriceTB.Text;

                        if (Convert.ToDouble(price) > Convert.ToDouble(existingPrice))
                        {
                            bPriceIncreasing = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bPriceIncreasing = false;
                        }

                        ScreenStockData(symbol, price, bPriceIncreasing);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You'd want to poll the DOM.... maybe use a FluentWait: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html  So get the initial value and start a FluentWait that returns when value is not initial value...

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins, that might work but not sure. I was thinking of a TextChanged event handler for a Text Box but using WebElement and Selenium. From that FluentWait class not sure how that would go. Maybe an example. I want to eliminate the Timer.